Zsh complete files only with vim and cat command
I want the zsh tab completion to only show files with commands like vim and cat and maybe a few others where you essentially want to operate on files only. I am not sure how to do so, I tried following but couldn't make it work
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

_vim_completion() {
  _path_files -W "$PWD"
}

compdef _vim_completion vim

I am new to zsh completions so any help/pointers would be helpful.
